# what does this type of declaration mean in c++?

Tags: c++, initialization

I can't understand this; please describe it.
This is C++ code:

```
int upper(0), lower(0);
```

Comment: That means `int upper = 0, lower = 0;` written as [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).

Answer (score 4):

As noted in @dxiv's comment, this is direct initialization of the upper and lower variables. The following syntax is also direct initialization:

```
int even_lower{0};
```

when applied to non-class type objects. When applied to objects of class type, it invokes the relevant constructor or conversion operator.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to add all possible ways to assign a variable in here with the difference

> 1

```
int upper=0, lower=0;
will assign upper as 0 and lower as 0
```

> 2 constructor initialization with single value

```
int upper(0), lower(0);
will assign upper as 0 and lower as 0
```

> 3  constructor initialization with multiple values will initialize a variable with the last value

```
int upper=(0,1,2,3), lower=(44,55,6,77,-5);
will assign upper as 3 and lower as -5
```

> 4  Uniform Initialization takes only single value you can't have multiple values in here

```
int upper{0}, lower{0};
will assign upper as 0 and lower as 0
```

> 5 you can use = in both constructor and uniform initialization for single values

```
int upper={0}, lower={0};
will assign upper as 0 and lower as 0
```